# My React Component is rendering twice and then getting redirected to homepage

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs and creating a test quiz project with it. The plan is only logged-in users will be able to access a quiz.

I am using react-router. When I have already accessed the website and then accessing different pages, it's not causing any problem. but when I am trying to access a route directly, the component of that route is rendering twice and then getting redirected to the home page. To clarify the situation with an example, I have a route /quiz. when I visit http://localhost:3000/quiz directly in the browser, it prints the following message in the console.

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Quiz.js:10 Quiz rendered
Quiz.js:10 Quiz rendered
app.js:5 works
```

then I am being redirected to http://localhost:3000/.

So, my problems are:

- I am getting rendered twice
- I am being redirected.

I have attached the route and quiz component here. What is causing the issue?

Routes.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../public_page_components/Home'
import About from '../public_page_components/About'
import SearchPage from '../product_search_components/SearchPage'
import NoMatch from '../public_page_components/NoMatch'
import MyNav from './MyNav'
import Todo from '../public_page_components/Todo'
import Quiz from '../public_page_components/Quiz'
import Footer from '../public_page_components/Footer'


export default function Routes(props) {
    var isSigned = localStorage.getItem('scs_user_logged_in') ? true : false
    const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(isSigned)


    return (
        <Router>
            <MyNav signedIn={signedIn} setSignedIn={setSignedIn} search_item={props.search_item} setSearchItem={props.setSearchItem}/>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact>
                    <Home  search_item={props.search_item} setSearchItem={props.setSearchItem} />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/about' exact component={About} />
                <Route path='/search/:search_term' children={<SearchPage   search_item={props.search_item} setSearchItem={props.setSearchItem}/>} />
                <Route path="/todo" exact>
                    <Todo/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/quiz" exact>
                    <Quiz signedIn={signedIn} setSignedIn={setSignedIn}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
                
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Quiz.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'



export default function Quiz(props) {

    console.log('Quiz rendered')

    let quiz_menu = props.signedIn ? <div style={{textAlign:"right"}}>Logged in</div> : "not logged in"

    return (
        <>
            <div style={{minHeight:"80vh"}}>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <h1>
                        Quiz
                    </h1>
                </Col>
                <Col style={{display:"flex", alignItems:"center"}}>
                {quiz_menu}
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{margin:"5px 0px"}}>
                <Col xs={9} style={{backgroundColor:"blue"}}>
                test
                </Col>
                <Col xs={3} style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}>
                    test
                </Col>
            </Row>
            </div>

            
        </>


    )
}
```

MyNav.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
// import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Searchfield from '../product_search_components/Searchfield'
import LoginSignout from '../login_components/LoginSignout'
import MenuButtons from './MenuButtons'

export default function MyNav(props) {
    
    var menu = props.signedIn ? <LoginSignout  setSignedIn={props.setSignedIn}/> : <MenuButtons setSignedIn={props.setSignedIn}/>

    return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand><span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Test</span></Navbar.Brand>

            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Link className='nav-link' to="/">Home</Link>
                    <Link className='nav-link' to="/about">About</Link>
                    <Link className='nav-link' to="/todo">Todo</Link>
                    <Link className='nav-link' to="/quiz">Quiz</Link>


                    {/* <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider />
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown> */}
                </Nav>

            </Navbar.Collapse>
            <Searchfield search_item={props.search_item} setSearchItem={props.setSearchItem} />
            {menu}

        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there any code to the `MyNav` file which might redirect to the home?

Comment: @moshfiqrony added mynav.js.

Comment: I guess you are using this for 404 page. You should use Redirect for 404 not this `<Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />`

Comment: Remove that route and let me know if it solved

Comment: @moshfiqrony i have got the issue causing this but the solution throws warning. i am going to update the issue in few minutes.

Comment: What warning you are seeing

Comment: @moshfiqrony if you visit https://chaldal.com and search any item, you can see that the route is changing dynamically based on what you are typing. i am transferring this search term using props. when there is no search term, i redirect the user to homepage. (which was causing the issue).

the code is: https://pastebin.com/VNzA6Tud

i am getting warning in this dependency array. getting: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'history' and 'props'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

if  i use [history, props, props.search_item], it causes the issue in the post.

Comment: i am trying to replicate the search behavior of chaldal.com but when there is nothing to search, it'll go back to homepage. so,
[history, props, props.search_item] doesn't give warning. [props.search_item] works but gives warning.